# jquery.ui libraries-override > Incomplete library definition

Tags: 8, theming

I tried to remove the core jquery.ui theme.css by writing into mytheme.libraries.yml the following lines.

```yaml
libraries-override:
  core/jquery.ui:
    css:
      theme:
        assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css: false
```

```yaml
 stylesheets-remove:
  - core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css
```

Both versions return an *Incomplete library definition* error. I cleared the cache but the errors remain. Does anybody know the solution?

After further reading, I put the code in mytheme.info.yml (instead of mytheme.libraries.yml). This avoids the error, but the "overriden" theme.css is still loading.

Answer (score 0):

What the OP worked for me but I needed to override additional libraries:

```
libraries-override:
  core/jquery.ui:
    css:
      theme:
        assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css: false
  core/drupal.dialog:
    css:
      theme:
        assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css: false
  core/jquery.ui.dialog:
    css:
      theme:
        assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css: false
  core/drupal.autocomplete:
    css:
      theme:
        assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/theme.css: false
```

The `stylesheets-override` didn't do anything for me. This should work for Drupal 8 and Drupal 9.